# Create calendar table of next year using stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, calendar

i need create calendar table of next year using stored procedure in MySQL.

on this code the problem is setting value of next year, because the result is

```
Procedure executed successfully
Affected rows: 0
```

I can't set next year in this part of code

> '`@tbl`-01-01' + INTERVAL d.i * 1000 + c.i * 100 + a.i * 10 + b.i
> DAY AS date

how do i set the next year variable in this procedure?

any idea?

```
BEGIN

-- create a 2021 year
SET @tbl = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR),'%Y');

-- create a calendar table 2021
SET @s = CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_calendar_', @tbl);
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SET @s = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_calendar_', @tbl, ' LIKE tbl_calendar_2020');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

-- create a ints table
DROP TABLE
IF EXISTS ints;

CREATE TABLE ints (i INTEGER);

INSERT INTO ints VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);

-- insert into calendar table 2021 from interval day
SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO tbl_calendar_', @tbl, ' SELECT
    cal.date AS cdate,
    DAY (cal.date) AS cday,
    MONTH (cal.date) AS cmonth,
    YEAR (cal.date) AS cyear, 
    NULL
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            \'`@tbl`-01-01\' + INTERVAL d.i * 1000 + c.i * 100 + a.i * 10 + b.i DAY AS date
        FROM
            ints a
        JOIN ints b
        JOIN ints c
        JOIN ints d
        ORDER BY
            d.i * 1000 + c.i * 100 + a.i * 10 + b.i
    ) cal
WHERE
    cal.date BETWEEN \'`@tbl`-01-01\'
AND \'`@tbl`-12-31\'
ORDER BY
    cal.date ASC;');  

PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split up the string in the concat function and have the variable outside of the string like you did in the insert clause. It would look like this:

```
SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO tbl_calendar_', @tbl, ' SELECT
    cal.date AS cdate,
    DAY (cal.date) AS cday,
    MONTH (cal.date) AS cmonth,
    YEAR (cal.date) AS cyear, 
    NULL
FROM
    (
        SELECT \'',
            @tbl, '-01-01\' + INTERVAL d.i * 1000 + c.i * 100 + a.i * 10 + b.i DAY AS date
         ...'
```

You will need to split up the string in the concat function like this every time that you use the @tbl variable in the query.